# camera overlay label issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

i am adding a label to camera overlay and i successfully added it

but what i am facing is the label is also appearing in preview of the taken picture

i want to display the label in camera overlay not in preview of the taken picture for adding label i am using the following code

```
UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
overlayView.opaque = NO;
overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[overlayView addSubview:topImgView];
[overlayView addSubview:btnInfo];
[overlayView bringSubviewToFront:btnInfo];

UILabel *label          =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0,290,150)];
 label.text              =@"Hold the bottle steady, left align the prescription label, and then take the photo";
 label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 label.numberOfLines = 2;
 label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
 label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
 label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 [overlayView addSubview:label];
 _infoLabel  =label;
 [label release];


//Image picker
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView=overlayView;
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
_imagePicker =imagePicker;
[imagePicker release];
[topImgView release];
[overlayView release];
```

can any one please help me how to do that thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to crop the image based on your overlay dimensions. You could try [this tutorial](http://niftybean.com/main/blog/16-selecting-regions-from-rotated-exif-images-on-iphone) which provides a good explanation.

Beginning iOS4.0, the images captured from camera are saved along with their `exif` data and rotation information. So, you cannot crop them in the standard way as you would with the `UIImage`s The link above deals specifically with images captured from camera.